# Inserting timestamp int Postgres in bulk with copy or pgcopy

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to bulk import some data into Postgres using COPY but I can't get my timestamp to insert in bulk.

Reduced example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "demo";
CREATE TABLE "demo"(
   time            TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL
);
```

I have a CSV file which looks like this:

```
1609459247.579
```

I try and insert my data using COPY:

```
COPY public.demo FROM '/home/myuser/demo.csv' WITH (FORMAT csv)
```

I get:

```
invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "1609459247.579"
```

If I want to insert the data manually I need to use `to_timestamp`.

```
INSERT INTO public.demo VALUES(to_timestamp(1609459247.579))
```

Is there either a way I can get COPY to use to_timestamp at insert time, or some pre-processing I can do to the CSV file so that copy will insert it? It's very slow doing it one INSERT at a time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have solved this. I used a `COPY TO` from my table to create me a csv the opposite way round with a format I know Postgres doesn't mind, then mucked about with Python string formatting to come up with a format that works.

Short version, in Python you can use a datetime formatted with `datetime.isoformat()` to create something Postgres will ingest using `COPY`.

Comment: Or you create a staging table that has the 'time' field be numeric, `COPY` the CSV to there and then something like  `CREATE TABLE ts_convert AS SELECT to_timestamp(fld1) AS ts_1, to_timestamp(fld2) as ts_2, ...  FROM stage_tbl;`